# getting errors when using having clause with aggregate functions

Tags: sql

I am having a problem while using having clause. The following 2 queries generates some error for the reason I do not understand.

Following query generates this error : *Unknown column 'number' in 'having clause'*

```
select avg(number),name from test
group by name
having avg(number) < number
```

Then the following query generates this error : *Unknown column 'number' in 'having clause'*

```
select name from test 
group by name
having number=min(number)
```

Why do I get these errors when I am having `number` column in the `test` table ?

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` operates only on the aggregated columns listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. Use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` for this case with a correlated query to get the `MIN(number)` like so:

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
WHERE number = (SELECT MIN(number) FROM test)
GROUP BY name
```

**Edit:** The same reason why your first query won't work, again, because you can't use `HAVING` with any column not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. If you want to obtain the same results of the first query you write it this way:

```
SELECT AVG(t1.number), t1.name 
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT name, AVG(number) Avg
   FROM test 
   GROUP BY name
) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.number < t2.Avg
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: also explain using having statement